# Timer to Show Parsing time c#

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a submit button in my aspx page.The "Click" event of the button performs parsing of ".txt" files,and stores the results in tables and redirect the page to another page.
Now the issue is the parsing takes around 1.5 minutes.I need to implement a progress bar along with a timer,which will show how much time is left for the completion
of the operation.This includes calculation of the time required to complete the Database Operations and assigning this value to the timer.
Can anyone help me on implementing this?

Comment: How is this a javascript question?

Comment: I was ready to go for a client side solution for this problem,that's why tagged as "java script".

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code (Ajax : UpdatePanel + UpdateProgress)

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" id="PageUpdateProgress">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                Loading...
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="Panel">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" onclick="UpdateButton_Click" text="Update" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>


protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //Your treatment
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Aghilas Yakoub.

Comment: Let me elaborate my question here.During a button click event,i am performing certain Database Operations-Let it me insertion of data to some tables,Retrieving data from some tables..etc.Now my aim is to calculate the time needed for these operations and show that in a Timer.How can i achieve this?